# Binary File Download with angular 2

Tags: angular

I need to download a binary file from an asp.net core app using angular 2. I found around several samples but are quite out of date and none of them seems to be updated to rtm.
  Is there any sample working with angular 2 rtm?

Answer (score 0):

In `Angular2 2.0.0`, you can use `arrayBuffer()` method to get a binary array from your downloaded data. Then you can manipulate it as you wish.

```
this.http.get("your/binary/uri").subscribe(res => {
    //Here you get your binary as an arraybuffer, do what you want with it.
    let data = res.arrayBuffer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I found this solution works for filestream returned by API.

this.http.get(this.apiurl, {headers: headers, responseType: 'arraybuffer'} )
        .subscribe(res => {
            let file = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/binary' });
            let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            let fileLink = document.createElement('a');
            fileLink.href = fileURL;
            fileLink.download = "example.xlsx";
            fileLink.click();
        }
    );
```